# TDS File Replacement

Tags: deployment, tds

I want to deploy some front end assets to the local web root of a site using file replacement. I can't seem to get it to work with a relative path in the target location field though. Is it possible to do this though tds or should I use a post build event instead?

The reason these assets aren't included in a project is that they are part of a third party solution but we still want this tracked in source control to try to make the project setup easier.

Most developer machines will be set up the same way for this project with the same file structure but I think it's a little more flexible if I can make the target a relative path so I don't need to worry about differences like drive letters and such.

The folder structure is as follows:

```
repo
   folderToCopy
sitecore
   webroot
```

I have tried the following using ..'s based on what tds changed my source location to be while using the "Make selected Source Location relative" option (changed it from an absolute path to `..\folderToCopy\`):

```
../../Sitecore/Website
/../../Sitecore/Website

..\..\Sitecore\Website
\..\..\Sitecore\Website
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, TDS does the file replacement based on the files published from the associated Website project.

You can then have relative replacements such as the following:

```
<Replacement Include=".\assets\folderToCopy\myFile.txt">
  <TargetPath>.\assets\targetFolder\myFile.txt</TargetPath>
  <IsFolder>False</IsFolder>
  <IsRelative>True</IsRelative>
</Replacement>
```

I have not been able to successfully get TDS to use the file replacement with files that are in source control but not in the project.

My suggestion would be to set up a build event that will copy these files to the correct location, or to create a nuget feed for them and pull them in as nuget references.